# When using color film pictures come out black and white. What's wrong with my camera (any idea approx repair cost?

Tags: troubleshooting

When using color film in my Minolta X370 my pictures come out black and white. What needs to be repaired in the camera? Any idea approximate cost? Thanks

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the camera. The film processor may have made a mistake.

Comment: Has the camera worked for you in the past? If so, what's changed (e.g., using a new kind of film? Using a new lab?) Can you maybe take pictures of the negatives with your phone (preferably, looking _through_ the negatives at a bright background) and add them to your question? What exact kind of film did you use?

Comment: Re, What DrMoishe Pippik said; There's nothing in a film camera that knows or cares whether you are shooting black and white or color. The magic sauce that makes the difference is all in the film and, in how the film is processed.

Comment: Please provide the film name/type you used. You can read it on the negative.

Answer (score 2):

Cross processed color film in black & white chemistry yield black & white images. However, the dyes that comprise a color image are still present. Cross processed film can be saved. Return the film to the photofinisher. Ask to have the film re-printed. If cross processed, the film is swished in the bleach solution for about 5 minutes and then washed and then put through the entire color film developing process. The result will be sub-standard color images that can be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your color film was almost certainly cross processed by mistake.

If color film is (cross) processed in B&W chemicals it will result in varying degrees of monochrome images... they often have a bit of a tint, but can be completely B&W as well.

https://shootitwithfilm.com/developing-color-film-in-black-and-white-chemicals/

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your advice. I will do some work on your suggestions - I certainly appreciate your responses. Donna